# Firestore import data-file is not correct saved (ä,ö,ü,á are shown as symbols)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i try to import some data in my firestore, this works quite well.

The data are german, english and spanish languages, so I have á,í, ä,...

My .json file is correct and when i opened it via xcode and vs code everything looks fine.. When i start my import and take a look at my database, those letters will be replaced by icons...

And i dont know why ... Does anybody know how to fix this?

As an example this is my .json :

```
    {
    "exercisesTest" : [ 
  {
    "exercises": "a_01",
    "description_d": "Stell dich schulterbreit hin und stütz deine Hände in die Hüfte. Senk deinen Oberkörper ab, so als wolltest du dich auf einen Stuhl setzen. Achte darauf, dass deine Füße während der ganzen Bewegung immer fest am Boden bleiben und sich immer über den Fußgelenken befinden.",
    "description_e": "Take a stance with your feet shoulder-width apart and put your hands on your hips. Lower your upper body as if you were sitting on a chair. Make sure that your feet remain firmly on the ground during the whole movement. Your knees should always be above the ankles.",
    "description_s": "Ponte en posición con los pies separados a la anchura de los hombros y pon las manos sobre las caderas. Baja la parte superior del cuerpo como si estuvieras sentado en una silla. Asegúrate de que tus pies permanezcan firmemente en el suelo durante todo el movimiento. Las rodillas deben estar siempre por encima de los tobillos."}]}
```

and this is my firebase db...

[image]

Import will be done by my .js file and works fine, except the icons :p

```
const admin = require('./node_modules/firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

const data = require("./data.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "xxxx"
});

data && Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = data[key];

    if (typeof nestedContent === "object") {
        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {
            admin.firestore()
                .collection(key)
                .doc(docTitle)
                .set(nestedContent[docTitle])
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("Document successfully written!");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                });
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i deleted my whole .json file and create a new one with a different csv to json - now it works...

used this csv to json + validator
https://csvjson.com/json_validator